# Can't load such file - toml-rb, although the gem is installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, toml

My Gemfile:

```
gem "toml-rb", "~> 0.3.8"
```

*.rb file:

```
require "toml-rb"
```

Locally it works, on a remote server - error:

```
/home/user_123/.rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- toml-rb (LoadError)
```

Although I've run "bundle" and

```
$ bundle info  toml-rb
    * toml-rb (0.3.15)
    Summary: TOML parser in ruby, for ruby.
    Homepage: http://github.com/emancu/toml-rb
    Path: /home/user_123/.gem/ruby/2.4.2/gems/toml-rb-0.3.15
```

What's the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using v0.3.15 of `toml-rb`. At that point, it was referred to simply as `toml`.

Try this:

```
require "toml"
```

Here's an excerpt from the [README for v0.3.15](https://github.com/emancu/toml-rb/tree/v0.3.15):

> ```
> require 'toml'
>
> # From a file!
> path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'path', 'to', 'file')
> TOML.load_file(path)
> ```

Beginning at v1.0.0, the `toml-rb` would be required like so: `require 'toml-rb'`. Here's the release where this was changed: https://github.com/emancu/toml-rb/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Comment: @Loku I misread the version. In your Gemfile, you specify `gem "toml-rb", "~> 0.3.8"`. Also, you can see when you run `bundle info  toml-rb`, it shows you v0.3.15 is installed.